# need to create a batch file to run at logon of each user to check for folder with its user ID in path & create if not ther, apply full control to user

Tags: permissions, batch-file

This script creating folder but it is applying permissions to all the users who ever logged into the server.

```
if not exist \\xxxxxxx\userhome$\%username%\ mkdir \\xxxxx\userhome$\%username% || goto :Permissions
:Permissions
 icacls "\\xxxxx\userhome$\%username%" /grant %username%:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Comment: You really need to rewrite your question before it can be helped — Write it in such a way it can be understood.

Comment: Sorry for making it not understanding, correcting here.

I need help in creating a batch script which has to run at every user logon on a server as a scheduled task. The Script has to check and create a folder in a network shared path with its login ID if it is not there already and apply full control to login ID to the created folder. And the script should not re-apply permissions if the folder already there with the login ID.

Comment: Example:
If a user with a domain login account: Test\12345 is logging into the server, when logging in the script had to check if a folder with its login account (12345) is exists at \\server\test$ shared path and create it it is not there. And then the script has to grant full control to the user login account (12345) on the folder that was created (\\server\test$\12345). Main thing here is that, the Script shouldn't do anything if the login account folder already there at \\server\test$.

Comment: I have got something below which is creating a folder and applying permissions as needed but it is re-applying permissions for all the users who ever logging into the server irrespective of the user login account exists or not at \\server\test$.

if not exist \xxxxxxx\userhome$%username%\ mkdir \xxxxx\userhome$%username% || goto :Permissions 
:Permissions icacls "\xxxxx\userhome$%username%" /grant %username%:(OI)(CI)F /T

Comment: @SaaranshGarg it would be really appreciated if you could help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Please use correct markdown for `monospaced code` in comments by encapsulating the code within two backticks _(one on either side)_; please see _Help_ link at bottom right side of comment box.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
@echo off

If /i not exist "\\xxxxxxx\userhome$\%username%\" (
    mkdir "\\xxxxx\userhome$\%username%\"
    icacls "\\xxxxx\userhome$\%username%" /grant %username%:(OI)(CI)F /T 
    )
```

Comment: Again! If exist is not case sensitive!

Comment: @iTwasnTme: True, just tested it.